# Split an equation string into a list of symbols with coefficient

Tags: regex, coffeescript

I'd like a user to enter an equation such as :

```
"(-6/8) + (2/3)x + (-2/3)bar + (5/8) = (-2) + z + (-5/1245)foo"
```

and then get an unordered lists of li as

```
  <li class='monome #{side}' data-value='-6/8' data-type='rationnal'></li>
```

or

```
  <li class='monome #{side}' data-value='2/3' data-type='symbol' data-symbol='x'></li>
```

depending on term's type for each member of the equation...

an ugly solution would be :

```
member_as_html = (membre,side) ->
  html = "<ul>"
  for monome in membre
    m = monome.split(")")
    if m[1]
      html += "<li class='monome #{side}' data-value='#{m[0][1..]}' data-type='symbol' data-symbol='#{m[1]}'></li>"
    else
      html += "<li class='monome #{side}' data-value='#{m[0][1..]}' data-type='rationnel'></li>"
  html += "</ul>"   



s = $( "#equation_string" ).val()
s = s.replace(/\s+/g, '').split("=")
ml = s[0].split("+")
mr = s[1].split("+")
ul_left = member(ml,"left")
ul_right = member(mr,"right")
```

but there's no verification on the string nor any flexibility on symbol length

finally to motivate people help me with those regex, here's the link of my working project.
You can play with equation till solve them : it's quite fun and useful for teacher :
http://jsfiddle.net/cphY2/

> EDIT
>   For now, Complex equation with any level of parenthesis and operator precedence ln, exp and factorial would be too much complicated for the state of devellopment. That's why I chose this convention of a simple equation made of a sum of terms. A term could be a rationnal or a symbol (any length) with a rationnal as coefficient. Any (better) proposal about the convention used to enter the equation would be appreciated (and especially the fu#@"@[|@king regex along with !)

Comment: you could use regex to do something simple like this, but it wouldn't be robust.  Do you need to support things like x(-6/8) or x-6/8 or (6/8x)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know coffeescript but here is a python solution, maybe it will get you on the right track?

```
s = "(-6/8) + (2/3)x + (-2/3)y + (5/8)"
s = s.split(" + ")
D = []
for u in s:
    if u[-1] == ')': D += [{u,"frac"}]
    else: D += [{u[0:-1],u[-1]}]
```